# Unable to see dfx balance after redeeming coupon

Tags: motoko, internet-computer

I redeemed a coupon to get free dfx cycles. However, after redeeming using this command

```
$ dfx wallet --network ic redeem-faucet-coupon <your coupon-code>
```

After 5-10 sec, this command exited the process without any feedback.
When I tried to run this again, it showed coupon already redeemed so I tried to check balance using this command:

```
$ dfx wallet --network=ic balance
```

[image: But it showed this error]

How do I fix it?

I dont know what I should try in order to fix it. I tried googling, no useful results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me solve the issue

Run this command

```
$ dfx wallet --network ic redeem-faucet-coupon <your coupon-code>
```

you may get a canister id.
set that canister id as a wallet